# Добавить в div текст (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Есть **div**:

```
<div id="name"></div>
```

Как добавить в него текст, в моем случае это имя посетителя:

```
var name = prompt("Какое ваше имя?");
```

**Что дописать в JS ?** 
*Без кнопок, т.е. заходит - спрашивается имя, нажимает "ок" - в **div** добавляется его имя

Comment: http://innerhtml.ru/

Comment: @Visman, а вы попробуйте задать `el.innerHTML = '<a'` в FireFox ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, и что? Мой сайт взломают, что ли? Пользователь может нарушить только страницу в своем браузере :Р

Comment: @Visman, как-то узко вы смотрите на проблему. FF в данном случае отобразит в `<div>`-е _ничего_. И это формально не будет ошибкой, но приведет к куче вопросов вида "а почему не работает".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы не используете jQuery, то это можно сделать так:

```
var name = prompt("Какое ваше имя?");

var el = document.getElementById('name');
if (typeof el.innerText !== 'undefined') {
    // IE8-
    el.innerText = name;
} else {
    // Нормальные браузеры
    el.textContent = name;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L237xu6/)

Comment: Можно еще использовать `el.innerHTML = name;`

Comment: @RussCoder, а если пользователь введет имя с разметкой? ;)

Comment: Ну да, тогда будет весело)

Comment: @RussCoder, а еще пользователь может украсить свое имя символами `<` и `>` не имея ввиду ничего плохого. FF при задании `innerHTML = '<a'` не отобразит _ничего_. И это даже не будет ошибкой, но приведет к куче вопросов вида "а почему не работает". Одним словом, в данном случае _нельзя_ использовать `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки в противовес очень правильному ответу от Dmitriy Simushev выложу ответ с кодом работающим через [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
var name = prompt("Какое ваше имя?");
var el = document.getElementById('name');

el.innerHTML = name.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
```

Пример работы http://jsfiddle.net/hgovn7tn/

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну что, все еще не работает?

Comment: Работает, хотя я бы еще `>` заменил. Вопрос только в том, а стоит ли использовать все эти замены ради применения `innerHTML`? ;)